# MS Access DLOOKUP with text and nested DLOOKUP for criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba, syntax-error, type-mismatch

I have a combobox on a form that contains search terms. The user chooses a search term and this looks up to a table containing the number X. The RVU (a number) of X is looked up in another table given the category is equal to the string 'PHYS'. I was using nested DLOOKUP statements to look up the number X and then use that number X and the string criteria to look up the RVU. Here's my code:

```
FH_array(0) = Val(Nz(DLookup("[RVU]", "[FORES IP Picker]", "[IP]= " & Val(Nz(DLookup("[FORES]", "[IP Number Xwalk]", "[Reference Name] = '" & Me.Ref_Name & "'"), 0))), ""))
```

I wasn't having luck so I broke it down to debug:

```
a = Val(Nz(DLookup("[FORES]", "[IP Number Xwalk]", "[Reference Name] = '" & Me.Ref_Name & "'"), 0))
Debug.Print "a:"; a 'returns value 279
aa = Val(nz(DLookup("[RVU]", "[FORES IP Picker]", "[IP] = " & a & " and [Cost Category] = 'PHYS')))
Debug.Print "aa:"; aa
```

I'm getting a syntax error on the line for variable aa. if I changed the code from

```
aa = DLookup("[RVU]", "[FORES IP Picker]", "[IP] = " & a & " and [Cost Category] = 'PHYS')
```

to

```
aa = DLookup("[RVU]", "[FORES IP Picker]", "[Cost Category] = 'PHYS'" And "[IP] = " & a)
```

I get a run-time error 13 type mismatch

All the variables are declared as variant and called properly. The array FH_array is sized correctly. I copied this code from another database that does the same type of nested DLOOKUP but it has only one criteria and therefore works. I can't figure out what syntax I'm missing or where the type mismatch is to get it to work.

Comment: @HansUp The result of the first is `[IP] = 279 and [Cost Category] = 'PHYS'` and the result of the second is error type 13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a single valid string as the `DLookup` criteria option.  Use the Immediate window to examine what you have for the criteria in the final `DLookup` example.

```vb
Debug.Print "[Cost Category] = 'PHYS'" And "[IP] = " & a
```

That is actually a "logical conjunction" of *two* strings.  (That will make more sense if you review the Access help topic for the *And Operator*.)

And since you're using `And` with two string expressions, Access complains about type mismatch, the same as it does with this simpler example:

```vb
Debug.Print "a" And "b"
```

So you need to create a single valid string for the criteria option ...

```vb
a = 279
Debug.Print "[Cost Category] = 'PHYS' And [IP] = " & a
[Cost Category] = 'PHYS' And [IP] = 279
```

Translating that back to the last `DLookup` in your question ...

```vb
Dim strCriteria As String
strCriteria = "[Cost Category] = 'PHYS' And [IP] = " & a
Debug.Print strCriteria ' <- just to make sure you got what you need
aa = DLookup("[RVU]", "[FORES IP Picker]", strCriteria)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed solution! It implemented perfectly and I understand what I was hoping to do now.